# jHtmlArea returning empty string

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg

I'm using jHtmlArea (http://jhtmlarea.codeplex.com/) WYSIWYG editor in one of my current projects. I have managed to integrate it in my forms in few seconds but the problem is that after submitting the form, the textareas changed to jHtmlArea editors return an empty string.

I confirmed this with:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Does anybody have any ideas where could be the problem?

Here is how I include the jHtmlArea in my pages:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jHtmlArea/jHtmlArea-0.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jHtmlArea/init.js"></script>
```

Where init.js is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#jHtmlArea").htmlarea();

});
```

And my textarea looks like this:

```
<textarea name="body" id="jHtmlArea" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Comment: Is your text area in a <form> tag?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to [jHtmlArea Source Code Page](http://jhtmlarea.codeplex.com/SourceControl/ListDownloadableCommits.aspx) there is a change that says ***"Item # 8502: Fixed issue with Text not getting Posted when Page is Submitted. Also, fixed an issue with the control that causes it to not work with an ASP.NET Postback."***

I bring this up because version 0.6.0 was released on the 24th of july and that change was made on the 25th of august. Perhaps you need to download the VERY latest version or wait for the next release.

If you're on that source code page, on the right side is a box that has **"Latest Version"** and a download link beneath it, try that.